# Android Socket read buffer size issue

Tags: android, tcp

I have a network Socket read that works fine in below case:

Sender sends bytes of `size_t` . Receiver knows value of size_t, and uses

```
do {
  long tse = System.currentTimeMillis();
  bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer,current,buffer.length-current));
  Log.e("time-spent",String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()-tse));

  if(bytesRead >= 0) {
    current += bytesRead
  }
} while(bytesRead > 0);
```

where `buffer` is of size `size_t`. While loop is used because, read doesnot grab entire data in a single attempt unlike write does!
Now if the sender each time sends variable amount of data,which is not known to receiver, the above code doesnot coming out of wuile loop. Also if i simply give `inputStream.read(buffer,current,1024-current));` it seems read only upto 1024 bytes and comes out of loop.

I want to receive variable amount of data ranging from `1kb to 500kb`. How can i using ordinary char[] arrays and TCP sockets(UDP as well) but not using NIO ByteBuffers!

Answer (score 1):

I would design an application packet structure to include the length field as the first byte(s) to be received. This will allow the receiver to understand how many bytes are coming in and plan accordingly.

Simply create a structure that looks like this:

- `length`: the length of the message being sent.
- `payload`: the data being sent that is of size `length`

You can structure `payload` to also be a little more descriptive than just `byte[]`; make an class that is `Serializable` that represents your message.

Once you have a well defined application packet, create a parser that understands the structure of the packet for the receiver. This parser will then receive the first byte or bytes and know that those bytes represent the `length` of the `payload`. It will then read the `payload` accordingly. If the `payload` doesn't match the `length`, the packet is invalid.

If you're forced to simply use `char[]`, you can do something like this:

`char[] message = { 0x05, 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' }; // 0x05 is the length field`

*Notice how `length` is not including itself in the number of bytes.*

This design is something that can be utilized on any platform for communication: from RF transceivers in embedded systems to TCP communication on Android.

Comment: hi i tried sending size as separate stream followed by the actual data. It only worked with a `Thread.sleep(50)`. without delay, the size data gets corrupted. Any other way to solve it ?

Comment: You should be sending the `length` along with the `payload`. For instance: `OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream(); byte[] message = { 0x05, 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' }; in.write(message);` You're not performing two separate writes. You're receiver will then need to know that the first byte represents the `length` of the actual message.

Comment: The situation is, i cannot add extra data at the front of payload. Assuming receiver knows first stream size is size-of-payload, and its size is known, any way to proceed?

Comment: As with your approach, `char[] message = { 0x05, 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };` requires that i have to first read `0x05` from the stream and then use it to read further, right? Here also it seems that the receiver should know how many bytes represents the size of payload!!

Comment: Why can't you send a `length` byte? `length` represents the size of the `payload`. This allows you to send variable packets.