# Best way for transfering files via socket in java

Tags: java, json, sockets, arrays

I have a BufferedReader object and a `PrintWriter` object. So I can work passing `String` objects made by `json-io` of any type (e.g.: List, Map, MyOwnClass)

My class have a `byte[]` attribute, this `byte[]` will keep a file bytes, such as an image.

The json generated of my class is very very big, obviously... Then i started to think that must have a better way to transfer files.

Should I change all the mechanism to transfer only `byte[]` instead of `String`? Does someone know what is the mechanism used by chat programs? Should I reserve the first 20 bytes of the array for the message identification?

Comment: message formats vary, depending on the nature of carried information. Your question should be: here is my task, what is the best message format for it?

Comment: Well I need to transfer text and file, I just thought it was a good idea to json both kind, but a json of a byte[] is too big, bigger than the pure bytes.

Comment: Why don't you create a `Serializable` object and pass it that way? You can also take a look at another question I answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138168/android-socket-read-buffer-size-issue/21138217#21138217

Comment: @bblincoe good idea. I could have a class with 2 attributes, a descriptor for the message type and a Object, that will receive anything I want. So I serialize my object. Then it will still easy programming and the data won't be too large. Thank you!

Comment: @LucasEduardo: Please have a look at my approach before using the Java-default Serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it to the socket **in binary**:

Assuming a `class` with one `String` and one `byte[]`.

1. The `String`

   - The length of the `String` is written with [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html).[`writeInt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt%28int%29) (or methods for smaller integers) and then [`OutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html).[`write(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28byte%5b%5d%29) on the return value of [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).[`getBytes(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29) with the charset explicitly specified.
2. The `byte[]`

   - The length is written with [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html).[`writeInt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt%28int%29) (or methods for smaller integers) and then [`OutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html).[`write(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28byte%5b%5d%29) for the `byte[]` to transfer.

On the other side you would do the exact opposite of this procedure.

I chose this *binary* approach over JSON because even though you *could* transmit the `byte[]` with JSON almost as efficiently as in binary, it would defeat the very purpose of JSON: being human-readable.

Comment: Doing this way, I could GZIP the bytes also, it will still binary, is that a good practice?

Comment: For the String part, is it also possible to write using `DataOutputStream.writeUTF(str)` and read using `DataInputStream.readUTF()`? The length and explicit charset can then be skipped.

Comment: @LucasEduardo Gzipping transfer bytes is good practice but you'll have to do this before you start sending, else you will not know how many bytes you are going to send. I usually create a temp-file with all the gzipped bytes, read the length of the temp-file (which is equal to the amount of bytes you are going to send) and then just copy the bytes from the temp-file to the socket outputstream. When done, delete the temp-file.

Comment: @vanOekel: I didn't choose writeUTF because it limits the length of the String and I don't know how long OPs String is.